# Android passing integer between fragment works but stuck, null point

Tags: android, loops, android-intent, if-statement, fragment

I've basically got an activity MainActivity.java that houses two fragments Fragment1.java nad Fragment2.java.

#### Fragment1.java

consists of a listfragment with various choices,

#### Fragment2.java

consists of an ImageView that displays an image depending on the option that was chosen from Fragment1.

I have managed to create an onListItemClick listener in Fragment1 which sends the list position that has been clicked back to MainActivity which then sends it to Fragment2, Fragment2 then displays an image based upon this position value.

However I seem to have run into a brick wall, upon starting my activity I get the following error within Fragment2.java:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I assume this is because a list item hasn't been clicked yet on the first Fragment1.java and thus Fragment2.java has no value of position to set the ImageView image to. Is there a simple way round this? For example by setting a default image initially and then changing it based upon the listitem selected?

Thanks

Code:

Okay so Fragment1 contains the following listener and intent, passed to CreateActivity:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            CreateActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    page = 1;
    ((CreateActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
}
```

This is then received by CreateActivity and send to Fragment2:

```
public void SendData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 1);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("myData", position);
        Fragment2 fragobj = new Fragment2();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

Fragment 2 then recives this intent and uses it to set the ImageView, here I output to log just to check the intent is working properly:

```
    int Position = getArguments().getInt("myData");
    if (Position == 1) {
        Log.w("myApp", "Intent Recieved");
    }
```

Heres my logcat:

```
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878): at    com.meme.hdmeme.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:50)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878): at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2313)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-29 12:54:18.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22878):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Too much text and zero length code. If you really want others be helpful, please post the relevant code to the problem and the stack trace of NPE.

Comment: Okay sorry, added code now

Comment: when SendData() function called??

Comment: SendData() is called within my class SectionsPagerAdapter which extends FragmentPagerAdapter. This is in the CreateActivity()

Comment: Post your logcat and don't _assume_ anything when exceptions are concerned ;-)

Comment: What is the code on line 50 in Fragment2?  com.meme.hdmeme.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:50)

Comment: In your SendData() method, make sure that this line is returning an integer:  
int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 1);

Comment: Line 50 is the following: - int Position = getArguments().getInt("position");